# How do I refresh identity token before it gets expired using flutter google_sign_in plugin for android

Tags: android, flutter, google-signin

I am integrating Google Sign In Auth with my App using google_sign_in flutter plugin. It is working all fine except the idToken expires after an hour. Just before it gets expired, I am calling signInSilently to refresh the token. It works fine for iOS but for Android it returns the same old token.  I looked into the code of the plugin and based on the comment on the code, it looks like by design, it doesn't refresh the token for Android.

```
Future<GoogleSignInAuthentication> get authentication async {
    if (_googleSignIn.currentUser != this) {
      throw StateError('User is no longer signed in.');
    }

    final GoogleSignInTokenData response =
        await GoogleSignInPlatform.instance.getTokens(
      email: email,
      shouldRecoverAuth: true,
    );

    // On Android, there isn't an API for refreshing the idToken, so re-use
    // the one we obtained on login.
    if (response.idToken == null) {
      response.idToken = _idToken;
    }
    return GoogleSignInAuthentication._(response);
  }
```

My question is if this is the case, how do I refresh the token (especially for the android). On the plugin repo, I have also found other developers complaining about the same issue but there is no response [there](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/issues/24#issuecomment-757544151).

Overall, my goal is for user do not need to sign in every time they open the apps even after a month.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if user is already logged in using Google Sign in and Firebase Auth to retrieve their data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649410/how-to-check-if-user-is-already-logged-in-using-google-sign-in-and-firebase-auth)

Comment: @StanislavBondar - No. I can login well with this plugin issue is when I try to refresh the token it doesn't return new token only for android. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, I can able to open the application without signing every time its works perfectly,

```
const _scopes = const [cal.CalendarApi.CalendarScope];
//I'm using google sign in for the purpose of the calendar so I'm using 
//this scope

final _googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn(scopes: _scopes);
try {
await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn().then((value) async {
  print("silently");
  await _googleSignIn.signInSilently();
});
} catch (e) {
await _googleSignIn.signIn();
}
final Map<String, dynamic> authHeaders =
  await _googleSignIn.currentUser.authHeaders;
//you can now use this new token for your purpose
_googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication.then((value) => value.idToken);
```